# Can $\int_0^{1} \frac{\cos^{2}(\pi x)}{x^2(1-4x^2)^2} \mathrm{d}x$ be evaluated for $x\neq\{0,\frac{1}{2}\}$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Can the following integral be evaluated for $x\neq\{0,\frac{1}{2}\}$ ?

$$\int_0^{1} \frac{\cos^{2}(\pi x)}{x^2(1-4x^2)^2} \mathrm{d}x$$

Some of my work is related to this integral and makes me think that it has a finite value (for physical reasons), but WolframAlpha says that it does not converge. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram is correct... If you look at part of the integral, for instance
$$
\int_0^{\varepsilon} \frac{\cos^2(\pi x)}{x^2(1-4x^2)^2}dx, \quad \varepsilon < \frac 12
$$

you'll see that its convergence is equivalent to the convergence of
$
\int_0^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{x^2}dx
$, but this last integral is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

Around $x=0$,
$$\frac{\cos ^2(\pi  x)}{x^2 \left(1-4 x^2\right)^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}+\left(8-\pi ^2\right)+\left(48-8 \pi ^2+\frac{\pi ^4}{3}\right)
   x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and then the problem.

By the way, using the $\large 1400$ years old approximation
$$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad \text{for} \qquad -\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2$$ you have
$$\frac{\cos ^2(\pi  x)}{x^2 \left(1-4 x^2\right)^2}\sim \frac{1}{x^2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$ which, probably, makes the problem simpler to analyse.

Just for your curiosity, the antiderivative does exist. It is not too difficult since
$$\frac{1}{x^2 \left(1-4 x^2\right)^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{3}{2 x+1}-\frac{3}{2 x-1}+\frac{1}{(2 x+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2
   x-1)^2}$$